# JavaScript callback function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, google-plus

Edited for more detailed description of the problem.

I'm trying to implement a Google+ sign-in, and I'm following the example provided by Google developers [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript). I wanted to make a really simple version, so I dumbed down the example a bit to the point of only having the sign-in and disconnect functionality; however, debugger keeps telling me that "Callback function onSignInCallback not found".

Somehow, the data-callback="onSignInCallback" isn't able to locate the onSignInCallbackFunction even though I've made it global.

```
        <button class="g-signin"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-clientId="44786453029-upk4dngu2cbvl357f0tifgh7vn8cui6d.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-callback="onSignInCallback"
            data-theme="dark"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
        </button>
```

Further down in my code under the body, I have

```
    function onSignInCallback(authResult)
    {
      helper.onSignInCallback(authResult);
    }
```

And the helper is defined above this somewhere.

Another thing to note is that the debugger is also giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" on line 38. For some reason, the error disappears when I replace type="text/javascript" to type="application/json". Not sure if that's relevant to my main problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your fiddle is majorly screwed up. html goes in top-left, javascript (no html) goes in bottom left.

Comment: I updated the js fiddle, but the sign-in is returning an origin mismatch error because it's not running from the local server I have set up in this case.

Comment: did you remove this function when you *"dumbed it down"*? https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/blob/master/index.html#L198

Comment: Replacing text/javascript with application/json likely just causes the browser to ignore the javascript entirely.

Comment: Don't I need that function? Maybe I'm not understanding the code properly, but the way I understand it is in the HTML for the button, the data-callback="onSignInCallback" attribute says to call onSignInCallback. Then the line you highlighted says that onSignInCallback calls the helper.onSignInCallback function. If I were to remove the code, the meat of the definition of onSignInCallback (located in the helper) would not be executed. Am I wrong?

Also, I tried removing it, and it did nothing.

Comment: Yes you do need it, i was asking if you had removed it (which could cause the error you are seeing)

Comment: No, it's still in my own code. I just tried moving that block of code around to see if it changed anything, but then I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: helper is not defined (which makes sense). I shouldn't have to move it around to get it to work anyway. I don't really know how else to show you my code apart from displaying it [here](http://codeshare.io/AVwAT). Maybe you could take a look at it and see if you spot anything out of place?